# Pressing Ctrl + - does nothing

Tags: gnome, keyboard

I have a mouse with 12 numbered buttons on the side. Button 11 is the - key. Due to this being a Razer mouse it is harder to rebind these keys on Linux (I know it's possible but I'd rather not go there).

In some games some actions are bound to the - key. This works without issue. Some actions are bound to Ctrl + -. These keys don't seem to be sent to the application (trying to rebind these keys in-game and entering this key combination does nothing as if the combination isn't sent).

Entering this key combination with just the keyboard also does nothing.

GNOME Settings shows that nothing is bound to Ctrl + -. This doesn't seem to affect any other key combination.

OS: NixOS 23.05

Desktop: GNOME 44

Comment: Using the GNOME Keyboard Display tool I can see that this key combination is not being sent if I press Ctrl + -, but - + Ctrl is briefly picked up.